# Not able to search Java APIs and libraries under GCP's "API Library"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I navigated to the "API Library" section in GCP, but I can't find or search any Java APIs or libraries like Spring, JPA, Apache POI etc.

Is "API Library" not meant for language/platform specific APIs? If not then could someone please explain what is the purpose of "API Library" section in GCP.

[image]

Comment: The term `API` means several things. In this case, `API` means `services`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your GCP, if you want to consume any type of service - whether directly through a console or in a RESTful way from your application running in GCP - then you need to enable its respective API.

If you use the filter on the left-hand side, then you will notice that even GCP Compute service has API for it.

[image]

So let's say if you want to consume/use GCP's Compute Engine or GKE then first you will have to enable its API. For example, I have not enabled GKE API, so if I try to create a GKE cluster then I get the below screen to enable its API:

[image]

Now, your point about Java APIs or libraries like Spring, JPA, Apache POI etc. - these are not "services" that are consumed by a client in RESTful way. In GCP's "API Library", you enable APIs for those proprietary or open-source "services" which are exposed in a RESTful way. For example, if you want to use Google Map services in your application then first you have to enable Google Map APIs, if you want to access YouTube from your application then you have to enable YouTube API.

So, all-in-all, GCP's "API Library" is to enable/disable services which you want to use from your GCP.